# Getting errno EACCES in Unix

Tags: c, http, unix

I am writing a simplified HTTP server in C, and I am stuck at generating a 403 Forbidden error. For example, if I go into a directory named "docs", and the user is requesting the file "foo.html" file in it, the server should return a 403 error if the file has not read permissions on it. Here is my code to handle this:

```
struct stat buf;
int error, status;

chdir("./docs/");
if(status = lstat(name, &buf) < 0) { //name == "foo.html"
   error = errno;   
}
chdir("..");
fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", strerror(errno)); //Prints "success" when it should be
                                                 //"Permission denied"
if(error == EACCES) {
   fprintf(stderr, "403 Forbidden");
}
```

I get this issue despite running the command "chmod 000 foo.html" in the docs directory from the commandline. I have been baffled by this bug and can't find what a possible source could be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

stat() and lstat() do *not* attempt to read the file - they just read out information *about* the file from the corresponding directory entries.

You will only get the EACCES error if one of the directories composing the path is not readable to your program.

Comment: So in order to get the the errno to be returned properly, would I have to pass in something like "./docs/foo.html" as the first parameter to lstat?

Comment: @PacSan: lstat("./docs/foo.html", &buf) won't try to open the file. You want to return the error message if the file can't be opened? The simplest solution is to just try to open the file!

Comment: if you want errno to be set according to your access rights of the file, you must do a read attempt to _the file itself_. lstat() only reads the directory nodes leading to the file. And since apparently you are allowed to read them, no error is returned.
Additionally, your strerror() call is referencing errno instead of error.

Answer (score 0):

Allthough uncommon, it however may be that the call to `chdir()` set the value of `errno` back to `0`:

```
chdir("..");
fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", strerror(errno)); //Prints "success" when it should be
                                             //"Permission denied"
```

So you might like to use the saved value of `errno` as it had been set after the call to `lstat()`, that is `error` as paramter to `strerror()`:

```
fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", strerror(error));
```

---

Also note, that `lstat` does only fail with `-1`  and set `errno` to `EACCES` if the user running the program might not access at least a part of the path of the file to be `lstat()`ed.

From [`man lstat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html):

> **EACCES** Search permission is denied for one of the directories in the path prefix of path.

---

Also^2 the code you should does not test the outcome of the two call to `chmod()`.